# Why is tf.transpose so important in a RNN?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been reading the docs to learn TensorFlow and have been struggling on when to use the following functions and their purpose.

```
tf.split()
tf.reshape()
tf.transpose()
```

My guess so far is that:

tf.split() is used because inputs must be a sequence.

tf.reshape() is used to make the shapes compatible (Incorrect shapes tends to be a common problem / mistake for me). I used numpy for this before. I'll probably stick to tf.reshape() now. I am not sure if there is a difference between the two.

tf.transpose() swaps the rows and columns from my understanding. If I don't use tf.transpose() my loss doesn't go down. If the parameter values are incorrect the loss doesn't go down. So the purpose of me using tf.transpose() is so that my loss goes down and my predictions become more accurate.

This bothers me tremendously because I'm using tf.transpose() because I have to and have no understanding why it's such an important factor. I'm assuming if it's not used correctly the inputs and labels can be in the wrong position. Making it impossible for the model to learn. If this is true how can I go about using tf.transpose() so that I am not so reliant on figuring out the parameter values via trial and error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question

1. Why do I need **tf.transpose()**?
2. What is the purpose of **tf.transpose()**?

## Answer

1. Why do I need **tf.transpose()**?  I can't imagine why you would need it unless you coded your solution from the beginning to require it.  For example, suppose I have 120 student records with 50 stats per student and I want to use that to try and make a linear association with their chance of taking 3 classes.  I'd state it like so

   c = r x m

r = records, a matrix with a shape if [120x50]
m = the induction matrix.  it has a shape of [50x3]
c = the chance of all students taking one of three courses, a matrix with a shape of [120x3]

Now if instead of making m [50x3], we goofed and made m [3x50], then we'd have to transpose it before multiplication.

2. What is the purpose of **tf.transpose()**?

Sometimes you just need to swap rows and columns, like above.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) has a fantastic page on it.  The transpose function has some excellent properties for matrix math function, like associativeness and associativeness with the inverse function.

## Summary

I don't think I've ever used **tf.transpose** in any **CNN** I've written.